# I want to make 2 buttons dynamic, so that when one is pressed, the other one shrinks and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uibutton

I have 2 buttons. "Stocks" one is default, it has larger size and bold, the "Favorites" one is small. When the second one is pressed, I want "Stocks" to change size dynamically. I tried to hardcode, but then realized viewDidLoad() is called only once. How can I handle this?

```
//MARK: - Stocks Button and Favorites Button

        stocksButton.setTitle("Stocks",     for: .normal)
        activated(button: stocksButton)
        favoritesButton.setTitle("Favorites",  for: .normal)
        disabled(button: favoritesButton)
        
        if favoritesButton.isSelected {
            disabled(button: stocksButton)
            activated(button: favoritesButton)
        }
        if (stocksButton.isSelected) {
            disabled(button: favoritesButton)
            activated(button: stocksButton)
        }
        func disabled(button: UIButton) {
            button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        }
        func activated(button: UIButton) {
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
        }
// this is in my viewDidLoad() function
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in the methods that get called when each button is pressed. So in the (for example) `stocksButtonPressed` you can set `disabled(button: favoritesButton)` and in the `favoritesButtonPressed` you can call `disabled(button: stocksButton)`.

Comment: the thing is, viewDidLoad() get called only once, and all the functions inside it get called only once as well. I have tried that approach, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, viewDidLoad gets called once. But you are also setting the actions which get called when the buttons get pressed. E.g. like `stocksButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stocksButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)`. That means that `stocksButtonPressed` gets called every time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The is another way to do it. Declare your buttons, set constraints an use CGAffineTransform in UIview.animate:

```
class yourControllerController: UIViewController {

let saveButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .yellow
    button.setTitle("Button 2", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let saveButton2: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .black
    button.setTitle("Button 1", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // add function to your button
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
    saveButton2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.backgroundColor = .red
    
    // set constraints
    view.addSubview(saveButton)
    saveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    saveButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    saveButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    saveButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(saveButton2)
    saveButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    saveButton2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.topAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    saveButton2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    saveButton2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    saveButton2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: saveButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // first state of small button
    let tarnsform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    saveButton.transform = tarnsform
    saveButton.alpha = 0.5
    saveButton.isEnabled = true
    saveButton2.isEnabled = false
}

var controlButtons = 0 // set a value to control button state

@objc fileprivate func yourFunction() {
    
    if self.controlButtons == 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0) {
            let tarnsform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
            self.saveButton2.transform = tarnsform
            self.saveButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.saveButton.alpha = 1
            self.saveButton2.alpha = 0.5 // after that you can set buttons title color
            
            self.saveButton.isEnabled = false
            self.saveButton2.isEnabled = true
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.controlButtons = 1
        }
    } else {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0) {
            self.saveButton2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            let tarnsform2 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
            self.saveButton.transform = tarnsform2
            self.saveButton.alpha = 0.5
            self.saveButton2.alpha = 1 // after that you can set buttons title color
            
            self.saveButton.isEnabled = true
            self.saveButton2.isEnabled = false
            
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.controlButtons = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the result

[image]